# Android encoding issue

Tags: java, android, encoding

I have the following line:

```
String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
```

Both, 'UTF-8' and 'UTF-16' are in Red representing an error with "Cannot resolve symbol".

Im not sure what to do about this, I'm new to Android and I'm not sure if there is anything specific I need to do in order to make Android Studio recognise them for what they are. Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Edit: The preceding assignment

```
byte[] payload = record.getPayload();

        // Get the Text Encoding
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have an unterminated string constant i.e. unpaired `"` before this assignment. For example the following would reproduce your issue:

```
"String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
```

Comment: I've checked and I don't have that issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Edit the question and post the code preceeding this assignment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace it with :

```
String textEncoding;
if ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) textEncoding = "UTF-8";
else textEncoding = "UTF-16";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for any conversion .

It will work sure.

createXMLStreamWriter(OutputStream stream, String encoding)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Could you be more specific about your answer? You do not detail where createXMLStreamWriter comes from. You could for example, make a link to the javadocs detailing the function of this method (and copy relevant parts into your answer as a quote for quick reading). Also, your answer does not respond to the error that JR3900 is having (the error, cannot resolve symbol).